# Flex: downloading files directly to the disk

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, download

Is there a way to download some files directly to the user disk, without browsing? (assuming they give permission of course).

FileReference does this, but does not allow to directly save files to the hard disk (if not through browsing).
Is there some way around?

Comment: Are you using AIR or is this a web app? As far as I know, it's only possible with AIR for security reasons (using FileStream). Maybe you could consider using SharedObject (which I'm not too familiar with so I can't give you any advice on this one).

Comment: Yup, Exort prettymuch summed it up : you can do it with AIR, but ot with Flex. SharedObject are usually employed to store informations that are relevant to a specific user...

Comment: In this case i've to download songs DOH! i've to redesign the flow of the application!

Comment: @exort You are wrong. A web app can write a file to the local file system. The only stipulation is that the event has to be triggered via user interaction( IE:mouse click ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify, for people reading about file downloads in flash, it **is** possible to save to the local hard drive in Flash Player 10+ (e.g. running from a web browser, as well as in AIR).

More specific information can be found in my answer in this question:
[Flex 3 file download - Without URLRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589913/flex-3-file-download-without-urlrequest/2591626#2591626)

To address enzo.rivello's question, saving must be performed in response to a user gesture (click or keypress) and the user must browse and select where the file is saved (i.e. through the file browser window). This is for security reasons, so the user has control over what is accessed on their hard drive.