# flash. AS3. Save NetStream to a local file?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, netstream

I want to ask how to save video and audio content that I'm loading from some site through a NetStream as an FLV file.

Is there any possible way to do this?

```
var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc); 
ns.play('http://somefile.com/file.flv');
var file:FileReference=new FileReference();
**ns.doSomething(file); /// ???**
file.save(data,"flvfile.flv");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with NetStream - it doesn't necessarily hold the entire file at any one time.

Why not just point the file reference to 'http://somefile.com/file.flv' - open that, then grab the data from it and save that with another reference once it has completed downloading? You can either run the NS in parallel as a separate operation, or open the NS from the local disc once it has finished downloading.

There's a good answer regarding downloading directly using a FileReference, and the gotchas it involves, here: [Flex 3 file download - Without URLRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589913/flex-3-file-download-without-urlrequest/2591626#2591626)

Comment: Thanx for you reply, but does it mean that file will be downloaded 2 times? One with netStream, and second with fileRef?

Comment: It depends. If you can wait for it all to download, no - you download it to local disk and then stream it from there. Otherwise, yes - you would stream one copy while downloading a second in the background.

Comment: I thought that in case video is downloaded, button "save" become visible. So... I don't know =(  Anyway, thanx